# can not change minecraft mode and player access

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

me and my friends were playing minecraft together and were building a city. this map was on creative mode and my user had access to run commands. after a while we abandon the map. i asked my friend to give me the save file so i can continue building on my own. when i put the save file where other maps are on my pc and then i started playing i saw that the map mode is survival and i can not run commands to change it. what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can open the server to your Local Area Network.**

If you pause the game with `esc`, you will find a button: "Open to LAN". This will make your world available to play for other players, but **only if they are using the same local network**, eg. they are connected to the same WiFi network or to the same Ethernet network. Like this, you don't need to worry about other players that you don't know about getting into your world.

When you are about to start the LAN world, select `Cheats: ON`. Now you can run commands in a non-cheat world.